# New Object Creating C#

Tags: oop, c#-4.0, inheritance

Class A :-

```
class classOne
{
    public int intOne = 0;
    public  int Sub()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public virtual int  Add()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Class Two:-

```
class classTwo:classOne
{
    public new int Sub()
    {
        return 2;
    }
    public override int Add()
    {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

Class Three

```
class classThree : classTwo
{
    public int Sub()
    {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Program.cs

```
classOne obj = new classOne();
classThree obj3 = new classThree();
obj = obj3;
Console.WriteLine(obj.Sub());
```

Output is 1.

My doubt is I initialized a obj with classOne .Then I assigned the same object with ClassThree using new keyword `classThree obj3 = new classThree();` . How does it call `classOne.sub()` . How is this happening ? My understanding is, it supposed to call classThree.Sub() .

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made `Sub` virtual, so the compiler will use the static type of the variable to determine which instance to call. Since the static type of `obj` is `classOne` it will call `classOne.Sub()`

Comment: This is why you had to use the `new` keyword in the redeclaration of `Sub` in class two. You are explicitly masking the method of class One. You don't use inheritance nor polymorphism here. You should add `virtual` in One.Sub declaration, remove `new` in Two.Sub declaration and add `override` in Two.Sub and Three.Sub declaration

Comment: `obj = new classOne();` here we are referencing new type to obj . In this case ,object type should change rite ? why is that not happening ? Why it is still in ClassOne?

Comment: @Dhinesh - Whatever you assign to `obj` the compiler will always make method call decisions based on the static type of `obj`. The runtime type is only used when you call virtual methods. `Add` is virtual, so the compiler will dispatch to the correct version. `Sub` is not virtual, so the compiler will always call the `classOne` instance.

Comment: @Dhinesh - so, if you want to call the overridden version of `Sub` make it virtual in the base class. Why did you make `Add` virtual, but not `Sub` ?

Comment: @Sean Consider this , if both `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` are empty but `ClassTwo` is inherited from `ClassOne` . In this case , first I am initializing a object using `ClassOne` , then i am initializing same object using `ClassTwo` by `new` keyword . Now as per `new` keyword we assigning new reference to a `ClassOne` object , then why the type of the object still remains to `ClassOne` didn't change?

Comment: @Dhinesh - the runtime type has changed, but the variable you have assigned the instances to have a fixed static type. It's the type of the variable that is used to decide what method to call. If you call a method against that type which is virtual it will dispatch to the correct implementation. If you call a non-virtual method is will call the implementation of the type of the variable, not what the variable points to.